# How to auto sync or intiate sync scheduler in microsoft azure?

Tags: web, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed a web application in azure by placing the app project in one drive. I keep updating an excel file file which is present in the app project. But the changes are not reflecting in the website until or unless I manual trigger sync button. Is there any option to generate auto sync or keep a sync scheduler to solve this problem? Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, sync from a OneDrive cloud folder is a manual deployment method in Azure Deployment Center, which means you **have to** sync your files manually. [(1)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-content-sync#synchronize-content)If you do want to auto sync your project, I recommend you to use any one of the [Continuous Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment) methods(I prefer GitHub). That means once you finish and save your update, the web app will sync the files automatically.
Like this:
[image: Like this.]